# Checking syntax of SFRestRequest

Tags: soql, sfrestrequest

I am unable to get a response back ("didloadresponse" doesn't fire) from SFRestRequest and I am not sure why. Is the syntax of _queryParams correct?[image: screengrab]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you implement the other delegate methods? If your request resulted in an error, it's not going to call `request:didLoadResponse:` -- it will instead call one of the other 3 (failure) delegate methods.

Alternatively, did you try this query using the block query method and specify a failure block?

Comment: no error occurred, it just never stepped into "didloadresponse". I've attached additional screen grab to show other delegate methods. I have checked the SOQL in SOQLXplorer and get a full set oaf 200 records returned.

Comment: Did your request time out? Was it canceled? Was there an error?

Comment: Request did not time out, although how could I definitively tell? It may have cancelled but how could I tell, no eror message in debugger. It stepped out of send:request and straight into numberofsectionsintableview, bypassing didloadresponse and other methods.

Comment: If your request did not complete successfully, it should have called one of the three failure delegate methods. Which did it call?

Comment: that's just the thing Jonathan, the three failure delegates are listed there in the screenshot right? none of them fire, and the success delegate doesn't fire either, therefore I can only conclude that if nothing comes back to the delegates,  the SFRestRequest falls over before it gets to generate success or fail delegates. Should I be looking somehwere else? Is there a way of stepping through every little stage (outside of the class maybe and on the journey of SFRestRequest takes through it's own classes?). Excuse my language by the way, I am not a very experienced developer.

Comment: The SDK is open-source, so you can definitely trace an `SFRestRequest` through its lifecycle; that might be a good thing for you to try next. Another possibility is that the request's delegate is either not set or lost somehow, or possibly an internal SDK error. If you can repeat this behavior using a single query, that might be a good issue to log on github.

Comment: Do you know how I would trace SFRestRequest through its lifecycle? Do you know how I would check to see if the delegate is not set or lost? I will with a single query

Answer (score 1):

I am new to iOS development, but I had a similar problem and fixed it by changing `jsonResponse` to `dataResponse`; suddenly it hits my breakpoint.

```
- (void)request:(SFRestRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(id)dataResponse { 

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't follow either of you. I didn't ask a new question but pointed out that I too had a similar problem and this was how I fixed it.